# Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This doesn't work:

// Extract data items from dataset

I've been all over the web for two days, including previous answers here

```
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0)
        {
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
```

Connected successfully
Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows in E:\web\peoplespoll\htdocs\TableTest.php on line 64
0 result
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::close() in E:\web\peoplespoll\htdocs\TableTest.php:83 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\web\peoplespoll\htdocs\TableTest.php on line 83

Comment: if ($result-> num_rows > 0)
            {
            while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
                {          
                echo 
                    "<tr>
                        <td>" . $row["description"]. "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["voteyes"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["voteno"] .  "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["votehuh"] . "</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "0 result";
            }

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `mysqli` syntax, but you're using PDO. It should be:

```
if ($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm learning MySQL, PHP, PDO on the fly as I code.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.